# Accessing DependencyPropertyValue in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

Let's say i have a ViewModel in the DataContext of a Control having a DependencyProperty:

AControl.cs:

```
class AControl : Control /* could be another class e.g. Viewbox, Label */
{
    public AControl()
    {
        DataContext = new AControlViewModel(/* this ?? */);
    }


    public int AProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(APropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(APropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty APropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AProperty", typeof(int), 
        typeof(AClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

AControlViewModel.cs:

```
class AControlViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Some actions accessing AProperty for the Control 
        // in whose DataContext 'this' is in
    }

    // EDIT: Property added
    private int vMProperty;
    public int VMProperty 
    {
        get { return vMProperty; }
        set
        {
             if (vMProperty == value)
                 return;

             vMProperty = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("VMProperty"); // In ViewModelBase
        } 
    } 
}
```

<strike>I know it is possible to pass a this-reference from the Control, but only from codebehind. How to do this correct (if there ist an easier way than passing the reference) and</strike>  how to do it from Xaml?
And how to get a notification if the value of AProperty changed?

**EDIT:** 
In the style of another Control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type namespace:AnotherControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type namespace:AnotherControl}"> 
                <Border>
                    <namespace:AControl AProperty="{TemplateBinding AnotherProperty}">
                        <!-- This Binding replaces the Binding 'AProperty="{Binding VMProperty}' inside AControl. 
                             I think I have to bind to VMProperty instead of AProperty... but how?-->
                    </namespace:AControl> 
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property (including INotifyPropertyChanged implementation) to the ViewModel and bind it to the property of the view.

That's it.

Now you can access the value of the property in the View.

Do not try to get a reference to the View in the ViewModel, that way you break the MVVM pattern.

Comment: So I can't get a value from the View to the ViewModel?

Comment: And which pattern would that be?

Comment: Yes you can get the value because through the binding the value is synchronized to the property on the view model. If you don't know the MVVM pattern you should learn it, it is more or less the best fitting pattern for WPF applications.

Comment: Do I have to use a 'OneWayToSource'-Binding because I have to set it to the DependencyProperty in the View?

Comment: In the Xaml of the view: `<AControl AProperty="{Binding VMProperty}" />` That will default to a TwoWay binding and that should be ok.

Comment: But if I set up another Binding with AControl.AProperty as target the Binding gets lost.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you add some code or explanation to your question?

Comment: This does not make a lot of sense. Why would you set the binding in the control if you are going to set it in the template again? (Or vise versa). Set it in one of both.

Comment: The only reason to set the Binding in the Control is to get the value from AControl to AControlViewModel therefore, it has to be a 'OneWayToSource'-Binding (or a TwoWay one) as I can't apply the Binding to VMProperty. The ViewModel needs the value to compute the values of other properties.

Comment: Yes, that is how a binding works. You always set it up in the VIEW not in the ViewModel because the ViewModel does not know anything about the View in MVVM.